# How to create importable backup of SQLite database with Ionic 2

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic2, database-backups

In my Ionic 2 App I want to have an backup function. I've got a SQLite DB with a lot of data. This data should be imporatable to the App again. My idea was, to export these data as SQL with [uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter) and save this sql to a file (with [Cordova writeFile](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/)). The import function loads the file (File.readAsText) and writes the data to DB again with importSqlToDb.

**On button click:**

```
// trigger export
this.dbService.dumpDatabase();
// trigger import
this.dbService.importDatabase();
```

**DBService:**

```
public dumpDatabase() {
   let _self = this;
   (<any>window).cordova.plugins.sqlitePorter.exportDbToSql(this.database, {
     successFn: function (sql, count) {
       if (count > 0) {
         _self.fileService.exportSQLToFile(sql);
       } else {
         // show message
       }
     },
     dataOnly: true
  });
}

public importDatabase() {
   this.fileService.importSQLFromFile().then((sql) => {
    (<any>window).cordova.plugins.sqlitePorter.importSqlToDb(this.database, sql, {
    successFn: function (count) {
      alert("Successfully imported " + count + " SQL statements to DB");
    },
    errorFn: function (error) {
      alert("The following error occurred: " + error.message);
    },
    progressFn: function (current, total) {
      console.log("Imported " + current + "/" + total + " statements");
    }
    });
 }, (message) => {
     [...]
 });
```

}

**FileService:**

```
exportSQLToFile(sql) {
   let fs = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
   let fileName = "Dump.sql";
   File.writeFile(fs, fileName, sql, {replace: true}).then((success) => {
      [...]
   }, (error) => {
      [...]
   });
}

importSQLFromFile(): Promise<any> { 
   let fs = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
   let fileName = "Dump.sql";

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // check if backup exists
     File.checkFile(fs, fileName).then(() => {
       return File.readAsText(fs, fileName).then((result) => {
         if(typeof result == "string") {
           resolve(result);
         } else {
           reject(result);
         }
       }).catch((error) => {
         reject(error.message);
       });
     }).catch((error) => {
       reject(error.message);
     });
   });
 }
```

I would like to give user control of file location and to make it possible to choose from different backups on restore.

Has anybody implemented something similar so far or has an idea how to do it better?

Comment: have u done this is it working g

Comment: @RameshR not yet ..sry

Comment: any news here? I'm facing the same problem right now